# One Arduino board no longer recognized, but others are

Tags: arduino

I've been playing around with an Adafruit Neotrellis M4 but Arduino IDE is no longer recognizing it as connected. I've tried using the reset button but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. The LED on the back of the board does light up, so it's definitely getting power at least.

I have other Arudino-type boards and they're being recognized just fine. Mega 2560, Leonardo, Wemos D1, the IDE immediately sees them when they're plugged in.

Every other question I've been able to find seems to be "my computer can't see my board!", not that it sees most boards but not a specific one.

Tried uninstalling/reinstalling the Board on the Board Manager and Library in the Library Manager.

I have a 2016 MBP running Mojave 10.14. I've tried multiple USB hubs and multiple USB cables. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling Arduino IDE and CH341 driver/firmware. Currently have Arduino IDE 1.8.8 installed.

Answer (score 2):

The very complicated, intelligent, intricate way to fix this?

Press on the "reset" button 5 - 20 times until it starts working again.